# Boost asio not able to run io service on all threads., io service is blocking at first thread call

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am trying to create a multi-threaded server by following the example 
[HTTP Server 3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3). I have followed as shown in the example.

server code for creation of threads. **version 1**

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size_; ++i) {
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ios_)));
    threads_.push_back(thread);
  }
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threads_.size(); ++i){
        LOGV << "performing join operation for thread = "<< i;
    threads_[i]->join();
  }
```

**version 2**

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size_; ++i) {
  boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread(new boost::thread(
    [this](){ LOGV << "Intiating thread"; this->ios_.run(); }));
    threads_.push_back(thread);
  }
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threads_.size(); ++i){
        LOGV << "performing join operation for thread = "<< i;
    threads_[i]->join();
  }
```

version 1 gives me output:

> performing join operation for thread = 0

version 2 gives me the following output with 10 threads.

> [Tcp::Server::run@76] Initiating threads 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread 
>   performing join operation for thread = 0 
>   Initiating thread 
>   Initiating thread

I want to understand whether all threads are used, or only one thread that executed join operation is used. Can someone please explain where I went wrong and suggest if there is any good approach to do this, I am also using strand in the same way as example suggested.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: does the call to io_service::run ever complete? If there is outstanding work in the io_service, it will not, unless io_service::stop() is called. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand wether all threads are used, or only one thread that executed join operation is used..

The former. The `join` function will just block the  until the to be joined thread has exited execution, but generally all threads will immediately start to run once they got handed over a routine (e.g. by constructor) they can execute, irrespective of any `join` or `detach` calls.

In context of asio of course only those threads can handle I/O that made a call to e.g. `io_service::run`.

Comment: Can you explain a way to check all threads are being used or not?...
In the output, one thread immediately performs join operation while the other threads perform join when I terminated the program by "ctl+c", what does this scenario explains

Comment: "Can you explain a way to check all threads are being used or not?" If a thread did not start upon calling the constructor, an exception would be thrown. This is guaranteed by the standard. As soon as the thread 1 joined, the loop will proceed to thread 2 and wait until it's closed (if not already) and so on.
CTRL+C however will rather terminate your process altogether. No further `join` calls will be done.